# An extra parentheses in a call to a nested function in Python

Tags: python, function, nested

I'm studying the module of Mark Pilgrim's Dive Into Python Book in chapter 6, and I'm kind of stuck with what this line of code `return [getFileInfoClass(f)(f) for f in fileList]` does.  getFileInfo is a nested function and I was wondering what's the duplicate (f), the extra parentheses is for.  I was hoping someone can help me out.  Here's the complete function:

```
def listDirectory(directory, fileExtList):
    "get list of file info objects for files of particular extensions"
    fileList = [os.path.normcase(f) for f in os.listdir(directory)]
    fileList = [os.path.join(directory, f) for f in fileList \
                if os.path.splitext(f)[1] in fileExtList]
    def getFileInfoClass(filename, module=sys.modules[FileInfo.__module__]):
        "get file info class from filename extension"
        subclass = "%sFileInfo" % os.path.splitext(filename)[1].upper()[1:]
        return hasattr(module, subclass) and getattr(module, subclass) or FileInfo
    return [getFileInfoClass(f)(f) for f in fileList]
```

Comment: That indentation looks broken. Please try pasting the code without any indent, select all of it, then press the `{}` button in the editor toolbar.

Comment: I think `return hasattr(module, subclass) and getattr(module, subclass) or FileInfo` can be rewritten as `return getattr(module, subclass, FileInfo)`. To answer your question, `getFileInfoClass(f)` seems to return a class which is then instantiated with a single argument, f. So what you're doing is creating a list of instances of some class for each file.

Comment: That answered my question.  Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

`getFileInfoClass` returns a `class`; classes are then callable themselves -- calling a `class` by just a name returns an instance of it. The two pairs of parens in quick succession are just shorthand. It is effectively:

```
file_info_class = getFileInfoClass(f)
file_info_instance = file_info_class(f)
```

Generally, the two pairs of parens like that is probably a questionable decision, as it's not very readable, but I suppose in this case the writer deemed it reasonable because it allowed him or her to put everything inside a single list comprehension.

Answer (score 3):

`getFileInfoClass` returns a class, so `getFileInfoClass(f)` is a class. When you take a class name and write parentheses after it, you call a constructor.

So, `[getFileInfoClass(f)(f) for f in fileList]` makes a list of `FileInfo` objects.